# Space handling in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, whitespace

If a Document (Say a merchant name) that I am searching for has no space in it and user search by adding space in it, the result won't show in elastic search. How can that be improved to get results?
For example:
Merchant name is "DeliBites"
User search by typing in "Deli Bites", then the above merchant does not appear in results. The merchant only appears in suggestions when I have typed just "Deli" or "Deli" followed by a space or "Deli."

Answer (score 1):

Adding another option, you can also use the [edge n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) which will work in most of the cases, its simple to setup and use.

Working example on your data

**Index definition**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "index.max_ngram_diff" : 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
        "search_analyzer": "standard" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index sample doc**

```
{
    "title" : "DeliBites"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "query": "Deli Bites"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search results**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "65489013",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.95894027,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "DeliBites"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using synonym token filter.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-graph-tokenfilter.html

you should have a dictionary for all words that you want search.
something like this:

DelitBites => Deli Bites

ipod => i pod

before implementing  synonym be sure you understood all aspect of it.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/boosting-the-power-of-elasticsearch-with-synonyms